# The subspace $\mathbb Q \times [0,1] $ of $\mathbb R^2$ (with the usual topology) is

Tags: general-topology

1. dense in $\mathbb R^2$
2. connected
3. seprable
4. compact

I have no idea in my mind , so please help me to solve this problem

Thank you

Comment: Can you show that the closure of the product equals the product of the closures?

Comment: Making a drawing of the set and recalling the definitions of the terms should help quite a bit with 1 and 2.

Comment: @user99680: yes i can show this , it is true that $\overline{ A \times B} = \overline A \times \overline B$

Answer (score 3):

1) No, since $\mathbb R\times(-\infty,0)$ is an open set disjoint with the subspace.

2) No, since for any $r\in\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$ we can divide the subspace into 2 nonempty open sets $(-\infty,r)\times[0,1]$ and $(r, \infty)\times[0,1]$.

3) Yes, since $\mathbb Q\times([0,1]\cap\mathbb Q)$ is a countable dense subset of the subspace.

4) No, because for any $r\in\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$ the collection $(\mathbb Q\cap[r-\frac1n,r+\frac1n])\times[0,1]$ of nonempty nested closed subsets of the subspace has empty intersection.

Comment: Sir, in(2) what you mean by "divide"? Did you mean, $Q×[0,1]=(-∞,r)×[0,1] ∪ (r,∞)×[0,1]$ ? But I can't see both of them are equal! Please reply...

Answer (score 1):

for **(3)** recall that $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$ is dense in $[0,1]$ (standard fact about density, as easy to prove as easy to write down :) ). And then conclude by a standard reasoning about cardinality of such subset. (less trivial if you never saw such kind of reasoning)

for **(4)** just recall the [characterizarion of compact set in $\mathbb{R}^n$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem) . Your set meet this requirements?